# Context Menu on a Group Row in RadGridView

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

I found one old solution [Here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/context-menu-on-a-group-row.aspx).

But GridViewExpander is obsolete in 2009. Proof [Here](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/whats-new/release-history/q3-2009-version-2009-3-1103-1285738400.aspx).

How can i implement it (Context Menu on a Group Row in RadGridView) in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers... =(

But i found solution.
The are two ways to solve it:

1) If you need custom style for your GridViewGroupRow - read about [Templates Structure](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radgridview-styles-and-templates-templates-structure.html#GridViewGroupRow)

2) If not, then just use somthing like this:

```
<TelerikNavigation:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            <TelerikNavigation:RadContextMenu Opened="RadContextMenuOpened" ItemClick="ContextMenuItemClick" x:Name="contextMenu">
            </TelerikNavigation:RadContextMenu>
```

```
private void RadContextMenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = (RadContextMenu)sender;
        if (menu == null)
            return;
        var cell = menu.GetClickedElement<GridViewCell>();
        var row = menu.GetClickedElement<GridViewRow>();
        var groupRow = menu.GetClickedElement<GridViewGroupRow>();
        if (cell != null && row != null)
        {
            if (!cell.DataColumn.IsFrozen)
            {
                //Code for current cell
            }
        }
        if (groupRow != null)
        {
            //Code for groupRow
        }
    }

private void ContextMenuItemClick(object sender, RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentCell != null)
        {
            //Code for current cell
        }
        if (_currentGroupRow != null)
        {
            var menu = (RadContextMenu)sender;
            var clickedItem = e.OriginalSource as RadMenuItem;
            if (clickedItem != null)
            {
                foreach (var gridViewRow in _currentGroupRow.ChildrenOfType<GridViewRow>())
                {
                    foreach (var gridViewCellBase in gridViewRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (gridViewCellBase.Column.UniqueName == "PlanObject")
                        {
                            var val = gridViewCellBase.DataContext as YourObjectName;
                            if (val != null)
                            {
                                //.....
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //....
            }
        }
    }
```